# Laravel fazer um Update de várias linhas de um array

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer um update de varias linhas ao mesmo tempo, onde pego as informações de um array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ate o momento não tive muito sucesso, apesar das tentativas, não esta atualizando, e retornando resultado 0

o codigo atualmente esta da seguinte maneira

```
public function atualizarEstoqueLocal($input)
{

     $resultado = [];
    foreach ($input as $result) {
        $resultado[] =  $this->produto
            ->where([['id', $result['id']], ['estoque', $result['estoque']]])
            ->update(array_except($result, 'estoque'));      

        }
        dd($resultado);
        return $resultado;

        }
```

gostaria de obter uma solução, saber como corrigir
e fazer atualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teu código não faz sentido. Tenta assim:

```
public function atualizarEstoque($input)
{
    $resultado = [];
    foreach ($input as $result) {
        $resultado[] = $this->produto
            ->where([['id', $result['id']], ['estoque', $result['estoque']]])
            ->update(array_except($result, 'estoque')); 
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: fajuchem obrigado pela resposta, realmente essa maneira me pareceu mais logico e melhor, porém teste esta maneira e esta retornando resultados todos 0
array:3 [
 0 => 0
 1 => 0
 2 => 0
 ]

Comment: Sim, ele retorna o resultado do update para cada elemento, isso porque no exemplo que tu mandou ele faz 3 updates, e pode acontecer de 2 serem realizados com sucesso e 1 falhar,

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma solução usando o seguinte codigo

```
 public function atualizarEstoque($input)
{

$resultado = [];
        foreach ($input as $result) {
            $resultado = $result;  
            //dd($resultado['id']);
            $teste = $this->produto
                ->where([['id', $resultado['id']]])
                ->update($resultado, 'estoque');
            }

            return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: O resultado dessa função vai ser o ultimo elemento do array que tu passou como parâmetro da função, acho dificil isso ser oque tu realmente quer.